# Method POST with 500 status

Tags: java

For starters, I wanted to make clear that I'm a newbie at programming, and  for that I apologize in advance if this is something silly or if I can't express myself properly.

I'm developing a log in page that, when authenticated, redirects the user to another page. However, after that redirecting the page status is 500.

[Browser status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsjAY.png)

My validation code:

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/config.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        if(username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")){
            session.setAttribute("username", username);
            
            doGet(request, response);
        }
        else {
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        }
        
        
    };
```

My HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="Config">
     <input type="text" id="username"  name="username" placeholder="Usuário">
     <input type="password" id="password"  name="password" placeholder="Senha">
     <input type="submit"  value="Entrar">
</form>
```

And for ending the session:

```
session.invalidate();
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
```

*Edit:
Server log:

```
05-Aug-2021 20:01:01.912 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Login] in context with path [/Lattes] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [/WEB-INF/config.jsp] at line [249]

246:             </div>
247:             <div class="row footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
248:                 <c:import url="rodape.jsp" />
249:             </div>
250:             <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" />"></script>
251:             <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/transition.js" />"></script>
252:             <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/collapse.js" />"></script>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
    javax.servlet.ServletException: JSP file [&#47;WEB-INF&#47;rodape.jsp] not found
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:400)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:368)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:578)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:517)
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:347)
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:204)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.config_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fimport_005f1(config_jsp.java:502)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.config_jsp._jspService(config_jsp.java:391)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
        at Login.doGet(Login.java:65)
        at Login.doPost(Login.java:77)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Comment: Any exceptions in the server logs?

Comment: Yes, I just added it to the question.

Comment: The Exception states "JSP file [&#47;WEB-INF&#47;rodape.jsp] not found". Is there a `rodape.jsp` in `WEB-INF`?